# How can I verify that an excel file is opened through protractor scripts?

Tags: excel, selenium, protractor

I have to automate a test scenario where the user clicks a link on a website and an excel file(or any other file) opens.Note that the file is not getting downloaded,it just opens as an instance of an excel file outside the browser.I need to verify that the file is getting opened on clicking the link.How do I verify that through protractor scripts?

The file is being listed on the task manager when opened. Can I use robot class to check the task manager for verifying whether the file is getting opened?If yes,please suggest how to use that in protractor?Or kindly suggest any other method to verify

Comment: Being protractor, why did you put the "robotframework" tag? Or you meant " robot", Java's desktop automation package?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have anything UI related validation on excel file then i would suggest to use find-process npm for getting the name of excel from running processes on OS. Best part is that this npm covers all popular operating system.

```
npm i find-process
```

You only need to add few lines of code to check the excel process.

```
const find = require('find-process');

find('name', 'EXCEL.EXE', true)
  .then(function (process) {
    if(process.length >=1)
console.log('excel process found');
  });
```

[find-process npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-process)